# Can I buy the full version of Rayman Origins on XBOX Live?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, rayman-origins

Recently on XBOX I downloaded the demo for [Rayman Origins](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-AU/Product/Rayman-Origins/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d80255530884).

The demo is quite good and I enjoyed all of the previous versions (especially Hoodlum Havoc) so I want to buy the full game, however I can't seem to find it anywhere in the download catalogue.

How can I get the full game? I'm can't find it anywhere on XBOX Live..

I'm not that experienced with the XBOX Live interface / tools so it may just be somewhere I'm not expecting it to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not every game that has a demo is an actually fully downloadable title - some are only available in a physical disc format. .

Rayman Origins is one of these - it's not available on the xbox live marketplace - it is a retail title. You will have to buy a physical copy from a store.

Comment: Do you know if it's released in Australia, and if so which stores I might be able to find it in?

Comment: Yes it is, and any place that sells video games should have it (like GameStop/EB Games, for example).

Answer (score 2):

As of 24 July 2012, Rayman Origins is [available on the Xbox marketplace](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-AU/Product/Rayman-Origins/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d80255530884?nosplash=1).